# Transform tree object to other tree object - Javascript / Typescript

Tags: javascript, object, recursion, tree, transform

I got some tree object data from server and I need to transform it to Tree Object for antd design Tree. I can't figure out it solution, so any help would be appreciated.

**Given Input**

```
const dataTree = {
  tree: {
    SUBVERSIF: {
      parent: null,
      children: {
        RA: {
          name: "RA - Ragam Anak",
          children: {
            "02": {
              name: "RA.02 - Sinetron Jadul",
              children: {
                "03": {
                  name: "RA.02.03 - Kosong tiga",
                },
              },
            },
          },
        },

        "ARSIP-A": {
          name: "ARSIP-A - Arsip A",
          children: {
            10: {
              name: "ARSIP-A.10 - 2010",
              children: {
                "002": {
                  name: "ARSIP-A.10.002 - 002",
                },
              },
            },
          },
        },
      },
    },
    FASILITATIF: {
      parent: "FASILITATIF",
      children: {
        BN: {
          name: "BN - Contoh",
          children: {
            "03": {
              name: "BN.03 - inventore rem et",
              children: {
                "02": {
                  name: "BN.03.02 - 02",
                },
              },
            },
          },
        },
      },
    },
    SUBSTANTIF: {
      parent: "SUBSTANTIF",
      children: {
        BN: {
          name: "BN - Contoh",
          children: {
            "03": {
              name: "BN.03 - inventore rem et",
              children: {
                "01": {
                  name: "BN.03.01 - XTC",
                },
              },
            },
          },
        },
      },
    },
  },
};
```

As you can see, there is tree node data that maybe have unknown deeply children from one or some object. Now, I want to transform it to Antd Design Tree that have data defined by **TreeNode[]**

For the parent / root, they don't have a name field, so the title is retrieved from parent field, and the key field is retrieved from unique key from the tree object, and so on.

**Expected Output**

```
const treeData: DataNode[] = [
  {
    title: "SUBVERSIF",
    key: "SUBVERSIF",
    children: [
      {
        title: "RA - Ragam Anak",
        key: "RA",
        children: [
          {
            title: "RA.02 - Sinetron Jadul",
            key: "02",
            children: [
              {
                title: "RA.02.03 - Kosong tiga",
                key: "03",
                isLeaf: true,
              },
            ],
          },
        ],
      },
      {
        title: "ARSIP-A - Arsip A",
        key: "ARSIP-A",
        children: [
          {
            title: "ARSIP-A.10 - 2010",
            key: "10",
            isLeaf: true,
          },
        ],
      },
    ],
    title: "FASILITATIF",
    key: "FASILITATIF",
    children: [
      {
        title: "BN - Contoh",
        key: "BN",
        children: [
          {
            title: "BN.03 - inventore rem et",
            key: "03",
            children: [
              {
                title: "BN.03.02 - 02",
                key: "02",
                isLeaf: true,
              },
            ],
          },
        ],
      },
    ],
    title: "SUBSTANTIF",
    key: "SUBSTANTIF",
    children: [
      {
        title: "BN - Contoh",
        key: "BN",
        children: [
          {
            title: "BN.03 - inventore rem et",
            key: "03",
            children: [
              {
                title: "BN.03.01 - XTC",
                key: "01",
                isLeaf: true,
              },
            ],
          },
        ],
      },
    ],
  },
];
```

I'm very struggled with object manipulation, i was tried with some method for looping and checking data, but i can't deep down to my last children and can't move to other sibling data

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a recursive function you could use. It takes the `tree` object (not the top-level object) as argument and maps its entries to an array of TreeNodes. When there is a `children` property in the source data, the function is called recursively to determine the value of the target's `children` property:

```js
const convert = (tree) =>
    Object.entries(tree).map(([key, {name, children}]) => ({
        title: name ?? key,
        key,
        ...children && { children: convert(children) },
        ...!children && { isLeaf: true }
    }));

// Demo with example from question:
const dataTree = {tree: {SUBVERSIF: {parent: null,children: {RA: {name: "RA - Ragam Anak",children: {"02": {name: "RA.02 - Sinetron Jadul",children: {"03": {name: "RA.02.03 - Kosong tiga",},},},},},"ARSIP-A": {name: "ARSIP-A - Arsip A",children: {10: {name: "ARSIP-A.10 - 2010",children: {"002": {name: "ARSIP-A.10.002 - 002",},},},},},},},FASILITATIF: {parent: "FASILITATIF",children: {BN: {name: "BN - Contoh",children: {"03": {name: "BN.03 - inventore rem et",children: {"02": {name: "BN.03.02 - 02",},},},},},},},SUBSTANTIF: {parent: "SUBSTANTIF",children: {BN: {name: "BN - Contoh",children: {"03": {name: "BN.03 - inventore rem et",children: {"01": {name: "BN.03.01 - XTC",},},},},},},},},};
const treeData = convert(dataTree.tree);
console.log(treeData);
```

Comment: It's a great answer, i'm just done this just one hour ago but with so long syntax. I couldn't imagine if the solution can be like what you did, thank you trincot, your answer is very helpful!

Comment: That's a beautiful implementation.  And TIL that the parentheses I would use in, say, `...(!children && {isLeaf: true})` are not necessary.  I'll probably still use them, but it's interesting to realize.